# C array variable & address computation

Tags: c

```
int a[2][2]={{2,3},{1,6}};
printf(“%d”,&a[1][0] - &a[0][1]);
```

Here, a[0][1] and a[1][0] are two consecutive integer items.As each integer will take 4 bytes then it should have 4 bytes difference between them.So,answer should be 4.
But I think,address subtraction is illegal.And in Dev-C++,it generates compiler error also.But the given output is 1.How come it becomes possible?

Comment: If by "4" you mean "sizeof(int)", you're still wrong.

Comment: hint: you would get 1 with other types than int.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing substraction on int pointers, so you get a result in "sizeof(int) units".
If you run your current code, it'll print 1, because those integers are indeed next to each other.

What you probably want to do is arithmetic on the addresses as numbers :

```
int a[2][2]={{2,3},{1,6}};
printf("%" PRIiPTR,(intptr_t)&a[1][0] - (intptr_t)&a[0][1]);
```

Casting the pointers to `intptr_t` (in header `stdint.h`) is a way to do that.

`PRIiPTR` is a macro (from header `inttypes.h`) used to output an `inptr_t` variable with printf.

Comment: Note that `intptr_t` is not necessarily an `int`, so printing it with `%d` is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

No, it should not be 4.

Your assumption is incorrect: Pointer arithmetic is done in units of the type being pointed at (i.e. `sizeof (int)` here), *not* in bytes.

Your array looks like this in memory:

```
[ 2 | 3 | 1 | 6 ]
```

You are printing the difference between the addresses of the `1` and the `3`, which are adjacent, i.e. there's exactly 1 `int`'s worth of bytes between them.

Also, you're incorrect to print a pointer difference as if it's an `int` (with `%d`). The proper way is to use `"%" PRIdPTR` and cast to `intptr_t`.

Comment: How will it become 1 then?